# How to set a height with a matplotlib histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to make an histogram in python with different values and decided to try Matplotlib.pyplot.

Everything is working well but I need to define the height of the y to 15. At the moment the maximum height is the highest value but I need it to be set to 15 and I can't find how to do this.

```
x = [liste_pays[0], liste_pays[1], liste_pays[2], liste_pays[3], liste_pays[4]]
y = [liste_ventes[0], liste_ventes[1], liste_ventes[2], liste_ventes[3], liste_ventes[4]]

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xlabel("Pays")
plt.ylabel("Ventes en million d'unités")
plt.title("Tableau des ventes d'automobiles par pays en millions d'unités")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I tried things like plt.bar(x, y.height=15) and it didn't work.

Comment: `plt.ylim(top=15)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `plt.ylim((bottom, top))` function for this purpose:

```
plt.ylim((bottom=min(liste_ventes), top=15))   # set the ylim to bottom, top
```

Comment: top=15 worked, thank you so much, you're a savior! Now it works but it only shows like 2,4,6,8,...,14. Do you know if there's a way to see all the numbers on the left from 1 to 15?

Comment: @SimonF.-Smith you can use `plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 16, step=1))`. You can customize step size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.ylim[min, max]`

**Fix it**

```py
x = [liste_pays[0], liste_pays[1], liste_pays[2], liste_pays[3], liste_pays[4]]
y = [liste_ventes[0], liste_ventes[1], liste_ventes[2], liste_ventes[3], liste_ventes[4]]

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xlabel("Pays")
plt.ylabel("Ventes en million d'unités")
plt.title("Tableau des ventes d'automobiles par pays en millions d'unités")
plt.legend()
plt.ylim([0, 15])
plt.show()
```

When you need x, you can use `plt.xlim[min, max]`, too.